# How to disable write caching after switching distrO?

Tags: hard-drive, gnome-disk-utility

Recently I switched from Linux Mint to xubuntu. When I was using Linux Mint, I enabled write caching from the gnome disk utility. But now, in xubuntu in the gnome disk utility, it says write caching is on. I want to turn it off. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

- You can use command line interface:

  ```
  sudo hdparm -W 0 /dev/sda
  ```

  Where `/dev/sda` is the disk you want.
- Another way if would like, install gnome-disks

  ```
  sudo apt-get install gnome-disks
  ```